# Permission of Prgrams on Linux

Tags: permissions, firefox

I am a student of computer science and I am trying to learn and understand Linux.
I want to limit the permission of installed Programs on linux.
For example can I limit the access of firefox (as example) to my files. Because I think theoretically firefox (and any other programm) have access to all my files.
In android we can give permission to apps to access the files on the device (and deny it). Is there anything like this on linux?
Or this securtiy concerns are not true? and why?

Comment: You may want to examine tools like AppArmor, which is installed by default on a number of distributions, as well as the security methodologies employed by Snap and Flatpak. While it’s true that many applications can be configured to have free reign over a system, modern distros generally take a more pragmatic approach. (See also: Docker containers and virtual machines)

Comment: You've provided no clues as to your base OS & release. Some Ubuntu system have `firefox` run *confined*, where it can access user files (for the user running it), but it cannot access files outside of the users $HOME (though permissions can be extended to media); but you've not provided specifics as to Ubuntu product & package being talked about (as it varies; `firefox` you do use can be installed in many ways which influences restrictions).

Comment: There are two unix philosophies that are relevant here: 1) everything is a file; 2) do one thing and do it well. File permission is more often set on the individual files rather than the application running. [See here for more info on basic permissions](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-lpic1-104-5/). If you don't trust an application with access to your files, you can run the application as a different user (guest user is a great example). You can also create a user for dealing with and storing sensitive files as the owner so that apps executed by your regular user don't have access.

Comment: Also, applications don't have access to all of your files, only the files you allow permissions to the user executing the application. It's more common to have sensitive files than it is to have untrusted applications because all applications and updates are reviewed before being included in the default repositories. It's easier to trust applications if you only use trusted applications.

Comment: If you compare the security track record of Android and Ubuntu you will see that your concerns make no difference. More often than not, malicious Android apps run with access to user's files because people grant access when access is needed to run the app. It's better to trust the software and/or run as a different user than to try and play wack a mole with granting permission on a per app basis.

Comment: Also, [see here for more info on restricting access to files](https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-deny-file-permissions-to-everyone-except-yourself-in-linux/).

Comment: Also, as a novice user at this point, it should be noted that **changing permission on system files is extremely dangerous** and can render your system inoperable. **ONLY mess with file permissions in your user's HOME directory.** System files are already off access in terms of write capabilities and sensitive system files are read restricted to all users except root or superuser.